# Mitigate params in polymorphism as child requires diffrent params

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns, polymorphism, overriding

I have one interface, implemented in 4 classes.There are some overridden method that do almost same work in every child class. But problem is, there are some params in some methods that are mandatory for some children and unused for some children, It overlaps each other. I have to override method in all children that do not use that param and pass null too in some cases. I want to mitigate those params in such case that no null is passed, all usable params should be passed to overridden method.

My code is so complex, I tried to put example simple

```
public interface ParentInterface {
    void func1(String f1p1, String f1p2);

    void func2(String f2p1, String f2p2, String f2p3);
}

public class Child1 implements ParentInterface {
    @Override
    public void func1(String f1p1, String f1p2) {
        System.out.println(f1p1 + f1p2);
    }

    @Override
    public void func2(String f2p1, String f2p2, String f2p3) {
        System.out.println(f2p1 + f2p3);
    }
}

public class Child2 implements ParentInterface {
    @Override
    public void func1(String f1p1, String f1p2) {
        System.out.println(f1p2);
    }

    @Override
    public void func2(String f2p1, String f2p2, String f2p3) {
        System.out.println(f2p1 + f2p2 + f2p3);
    }
}   

public static void main(String[] argh) {
        ParentInterface pi1=new Child1();
        pi1.func1("c1f1p1 ","c1f1p2 ");
        pi1.func2("c1f2p1 ",null , "c1f2p3");
        ParentInterface pi2=new Child2();
        pi2.func1(null,"c2f1p2 ");
        pi2.func2("c2f2p1 ", "c2f2p2 ", "c2f2p3");
}
```

Is there any design pattern for this so that mitigation of null values can be possible?

Comment: If you *know* what child class you're calling, then you don't need to call the parent interface method.  Just add overloads to the child classes and call those.  If you don't know what child class you're calling, then you need to pass all the params that might be necessary -- no nulls

Comment: actually null params are passed to a function which call parent method. at time of calling I don't know about child. 
actually I want to explore some design patterns like builder pattern.